# In Harry Potter, does the Permanent Sticking or Sticking Charm work on the spell Flagrate?

Tags: harry-potter, order-of-the-phoenix

We know that the spell *Flagrate* allows the caster to draw with their wand, but the drawing disappears after just a little bit of time. If you are to use the *Flagrate* spell on a surface (e.g. Hermione Granger in *OoTP*) and you want it to permanently stick or just stick (e.g. Maybe you want to draw with your wand on paper?), will the Permanent Sticking Charm or the Sticking Charm work on *Flagrate*?

Answer (score 3):

A canon answer would be impossible, since there aren't instances of wizards combining the Sticking Charm with the *Flagrate* incantation.

However, if I had to offer an answer, I'd say that this use of the Sticking Charm is **unlikely**.

The Sticking Charm (and by extension, the Permanent Sticking Charm) is described as a charm used to stick one object to another. The *Flagrate* spell doesn't invoke an physical object that can be attached to something, but instead a fiery line in the air.

> 'Flagrate!' She drew with her wand in midair and a fiery 'X' appeared on the door.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix. Chapter thirty-four: The Department of Mysteries</sub>

And a flame couldn't be attached to something, since it lacks a physical form.